# My two usb ports are not working after my laptop ran out of power

Tags: kernel, live-usb, power-management

I was using my laptop unplugged and didn't check the power level, it went off. I plugged it in and now my only two usb ports are no longer working since then, am running xubuntu 20.04 and checking **lusb -v** shows **MxPWR=0mA** for the two usb ports

**lspci**

```
root@galvanometor-ZED-AIRPRO:/home/galvanometor# lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0f)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0f)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx, Celeron N2000 Series USB xHCI (rev 0f)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0f)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0f)
```

**lshw**

```
root@galvanometor-ZED-AIR+PRO:/home/galvanometor# lshw
galvanometor-zed-air-pro    
    description: Notebook
    product: ZED AIR PRO (ZED AIR PRO)
    vendor: I-Life Digital Technologies LLC
    version: V1.00.01
    serial: Type1 - 123456789
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=14.1 Tablet PC sku=ZED AIR PRO uuid=78563412-3412-7856-90AB-CDDEEFAABBCC
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: PTBTWXUFK10BLK
       vendor: Visage Telecom Pty Ltd
       physical id: 0
       version: Type2 - Board Version
       serial: Type2 - Board Serial Number
       slot: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: INSYDE Corp.
          physical id: 0
          version: ILIFE.WI314.NTNNEBN03
          date: 01/07/2017
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 3MiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb zipboot biosbootspecification netboot
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU  Z3735F @ 1.33GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU  Z3735F @ 1.33GHz
          slot: CPU 1
          size: 737MHz
          capacity: 1832MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 83MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch epb pti ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms dtherm ida arat md_clear cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=1
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 8
             slot: Unknown
             size: 32KiB
             capacity: 32KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 9
             slot: Unknown
             size: 1MiB
             capacity: 1MiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=2
     *-cache
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 7
          slot: Unknown
          size: 24KiB
          capacity: 24KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
          configuration: level=1
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 14
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 2GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: To be filled by O.E.M
             vendor: To be filled by O.E.M
             physical id: 0
             serial: To be filled by O.E.M
             slot: DIMM0
             size: 2GiB
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns) [empty]
             product: To be filled by O.E.M
             vendor: To be filled by O.E.M
             physical id: 1
             serial: To be filled by O.E.M
             slot: DIMM1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 0f
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=iosf_mbi_pci
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 0f
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:74 memory:90000000-903fffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:1000(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx, Celeron N2000 Series USB xHCI
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 0f
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:28 memory:90800000-9080ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.4.0-65-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.04
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: USB 2.0 Hub
                   vendor: Terminus Technology Inc.
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: usb@1:2
                   version: 1.11
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub maxpower=100mA slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb:0
                      description: Keyboard
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: usb@1:2.1
                      version: 1.00
                      capabilities: usb-1.10
                      configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=2Mbit/s
                 *-usb:1
                      description: Video
                      product: USB 2.0 Web Camera
                      vendor: Alcor Micro, Corp.
                      physical id: 3
                      bus info: usb@1:2.3
                      version: 0.08
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=200mA speed=480Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.4.0-65-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.04
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=1 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-generic
             description: Encryption controller
             product: Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 0f
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_txe latency=0
             resources: irq:78 memory:90700000-907fffff memory:90600000-906fffff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 0f
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
     *-pnp00:00
          product: PnP device PNP0b00
          physical id: 1
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
     *-pnp00:01
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 2
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:02
          product: PnP device PNP0501
          physical id: 3
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=serial
  *-battery
       description: Lithium Ion Battery
       product: SR Real Battery
       vendor: Intel SR 1
       physical id: 1
       version: Date
       serial: 123456789
       slot: I2C2
       configuration: voltage=3.8V
  *-power UNCLAIMED
       description: OEM_Define1
       product: OEM_Define5
       vendor: OEM_Define2
       physical id: 2
       version: OEM_Define6
       serial: OEM_Define3
       capacity: 42mAh
```

Comment: Boot from the live media you installed from and test them.

Comment: The `lsusb` output only shows current draw rather than capability. What does the output of `lspci` or `lshw` show for the USB devices? This is probably a case of an aggressive power profile 

Comment: Hi @david I don't have a bootable media anymore, I restored the usb after I completed installing Xubuntu

Comment: Do What Matigo is telling you but I suggest you keep a copy of the live boot forever you may need it again.

Comment: I will do that as soon as I figure out how to post the output here, am currently replying from my phone since  I use USB tethering to go online on the laptop.

Comment: Am not sure if I will be able to boot live media since the only USB ports are not working. I can use another comp to make the bootable usb

Comment: Hi @ Matigo, I have now edited the question to include the output of lspci and lshw